# How can I configure Python linter for the lsp layer of SpaceVim?

Tags: python, vim, liskov-substitution-principle, spacevim, yapf

The lsp layer in SpaceVim is great! However, there is a slight issue with the Python liner in the lsp layer. it reports the following warings on my formattting which is done using yapf using the following settings (.style.yapf). How can I configure the Python linter for the lsp layer so that it respect the yapf settings and stop complaining about the formatting?

```
[style]
based_on_style = facebook
column_limit = 88
```

[image: Warnings on Formatting]

Answer (score 1):

this seems colorscheme issue. do you have a try with switch to `one` colorscheme.

by default, if you are using Vim with SpaceVim. the default lsp client is vim-lsp. I think this plugin has provided option for disable error display. If you are using neovim. the lsp client is language-client.nvm. It should also provide this option. then you can do it in bootstrap function.

Comment: Can you share an example on how to configure the colorscheme to be `one`?